# Adding items to a menubar with a for loop - Pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qmenubar

I have a list of name and from that list, I would like to populate a `menubar` of my `QMainWindow`. Below an attempt of code:

```
list_name = ['Miller', 'Johnson', 'Robert']
self.menuName = self.menuBar().addMenu('Name')
for i in range(0,3):
    list_name[i]+'_action' = QtWidgets.QAction(list_name[i], self)
    self.menuName.addAction(list_name[i])
```

Here the error:

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not assign a variable to a string, you must do the opposite, besides it is not necessary that the variable has a different name.

To make it more readable, you can also iterate through the list instead of iterating over numbers.

```
list_name = ['Miller', 'Johnson', 'Robert']
self.menuName = self.menuBar().addMenu('Name')
for name in list_name:
    action = QtWidgets.QAction(name, self)
    self.menuName.addAction(action)
```

Comment: Awesome! Just a quick question. How can I connect the menubar items to the same def? Should have to include this kind of code into the loop: `self.name_action.triggered.connect(self.def_name)` ? Thanks

Comment: If you want to connect all the QAction to the same function you only have to use: `action.triggered.connect(self.def_name)`. If you want to filter in the function you only have to use `self.sender()`. Please do not forget to mark my answer as correct.

Comment: One more thing... How can I pass the name of the item selected as a variable? I did this `action.triggered.connect(lambda item=name: self.def_name(item))` but that returns `False` when I print the variable. Thanks

Comment: What are the def_name input parameters? `action.triggered.connect(lambda checked, item=name: self.def_name(item))`

Comment: Thank you for your help, by adding the `checked` my code works